# How do I set the next value of a table in lua?

Tags: lua

I'm making a text game, and in this game you have an inventory.
You search for items, and I have a function set to search for items.
If someone already has an item, then how do I set the next item to whatever they found.

To make it simple,
what I want is

```
inv = {}
if "player finds item" then
inv[nextvalue] = founditem
-- not the actual code
```

But I don't know how to get the set the nextvalue.
Please help!

Answer (score 2):

The question is not very clear, but I assume you want to use a Lua idom to append a value to a table:

```
inv = {}
if "player finds item" then
  inv[#inv+1] = founditem
end
```

You could also use the [table.insert](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.insert) function.

```
inv = {}
if "player finds item" then
  table.insert(inv, founditem)
end
```

Comment: thanks! im somewhat new to other lua versions because I usually use luau. This helped!

Answer (score 1):

You need `table.insert`

```lua
-- table.insert(table,pos,element)
local inv = {}
if "player finds item" then
    table.insert(inv, nextvalue, founditem)
end
```

See [document](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.insert)